# multiplication or composition?

Tags: ring-homomorphism

I am studying the ring homomorphism of the following function:

If $f: M \to N$ is a smooth function, then  $$f^*: C^{\infty}(N) \to C^{\infty}(M), \textbf{ defined by } \phi \mapsto \phi \circ f$$ is a ring homomorphism.

I know that the given function $f^*$ should satisfy that for every $h,g \in C^{\infty}(M),$ we have that $f^*(hg) = f^*(g) f^*(h).$ my question is should the operation between $g,h$ be  multiplication or composition and why?

Could someone explain this to me please?

Comment: There is a reason to use a different alphabet for the elements of $C^{\infty}$ and $f:M\to N.$ $f^{*}(hg)$ makes $f,g,h$ look similar. They are not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is multiplication. If $h$ and $g$ are maps from $N$ into $\Bbb R$ how could you possibly compose them? Only if $N=\Bbb R$.

When I write that it is multiplication, what I mean is that $hg$ is the map $n\mapsto h(n)g(n)$

Comment: but then it will not be a ring homomorphism which is what is required to be proved ... right?

Comment: After this $f^*(g h) = (gh) \circ f$ what should I do?

Comment: Is $(gh \circ f) = (g \circ f)(h \circ f)?$

Comment: Sure it is! You have\begin{align}(gh\circ f)(x)&=(gh)\bigl(f(x)\bigr)\\&=g\bigl(f(x)\bigr)h\bigl(f(x)\bigr)\\&=(g\circ f)(x)\cdot(h\circ f)(x).\end{align}

Comment: I have never seen this before .... multiplication in case of composition is like coset multiplication?

Comment: I fail to see a connection between those two concepts here. All I use is composition of functions and multiplication of real numbers.

Comment: oh, so you are looking to $f(x)$ like a new variable say $y$ and you are evaluating $g$ and $h$ on it?

Comment: Sure. That's how function composition works, right?!

Comment: yeah, you are correct but in the end it looks like coset multiplication